# how to get the rows property in gridview of devxpress with a button to edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

i have a gridview with devexpress my gridview contain a id ID="GriviewLV1" and i have a button in the row of the gridview to edit the record , in the event click of the button im trying give click in the button to edit but cannot get the property rows or something like that. im trying something like this but cannot do rows property because dont exist the rows property in grid view devexpress

```
  button_Edit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GriviewLV1.Rows)
            {
             

             }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

And for what exactly do you need row collection?
As far as I know, you can only manipulate with records (DataSource property object). Also it is possible to get selected row. Some my code examples with explanation:

```
private List<ImageSetMember> imageSets;
...
//assign collection as grid's DataSource.
//From now on any actions on imageSets object will be automatically reproduced
//as grid's row changes.
imageSetGridControl.DataSource = imageSets; 
...
private void replaceButtonEdit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //get focused row record's index at DataSource collection       
    int index = imageSetGridView.GetDataSourceRowIndex(imageSetGridView.FocusedRowHandle); 
    var selectedImage = imageSet[index].Image; //accessing to row's record
}
```